# How can i copy data from cells of one excel file to another excel file(in desired row and columns) in java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here is the code below to fetch data from one sheet. Now my query is how can i store this all output data, so that i can write another method to paste it in a diffrent sheet.

```
public void ReadCount(String Path) {
    String []module;
    int [][]status;

    try {
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File(Path));
        XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);

        boolean isPresent = false;
        XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int i=0; i<sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Row r = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (int cn=0; cn<r.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
                Cell c = r.getCell(cn);
                c.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
                String text = c.getStringCellValue();
                if(text.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Module Name")) {   
                    for(int a = i+2; a<sheet.getLastRowNum(); a++) {
                        Row p = sheet.getRow(a);
                        Cell q = p.getCell(cn);
                        q.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
                        String m = q.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println(m);

                        Cell k = p.getCell(cn+1);
                        k.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC );
                        double PASS = k.getNumericCellValue();
                        int P = (int)PASS;
                        System.out.println(P);

                        Cell l = p.getCell(cn+2);
                        l.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC );
                        double FAIL = l.getNumericCellValue();
                        int F = (int)FAIL;
                        System.out.println(F);

                        Cell n = p.getCell(cn+3);
                        n.setCellType ( Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC );
                        double ONHOLD = n.getNumericCellValue();
                        int O = (int)ONHOLD;
                        System.out.println(O);
                    }   
                    //return module;
                }       
            }
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The console output for this method is

ROW1
1
0
0
ROW2
1
0
0
ROW3
0
1
0
ROW4
0
1
1

Comment: actually i want to paste this data in a different excel sheet at various rows after some validation match.

Comment: What do you expect we shall answer here? You can store the data in each kind of `Java` object which is able to store it. This may be kind of array or collection. I would prefer using a collection.